# MySQL and C# retrieving records

Tags: c#, mysql

I am wanting to have the values from the two select statements returned via stored procedure. I can have one statement returned when its in a stored procedure on its own, but it wont work when two '.read' are present.

```cs
private void viewLeaderboard(int pgamenumber)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("viewLeaderboard", coon); // Select stored proecdure name
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pGameNumber", pgamenumber); // Add a parameter
    coon.Open();
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
           characterList.Add(myReader.GetString("CharacterName"));
           characterScoreList.Add(myReader.GetString("CharacterScore"));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        myReader.Close();
        coon.Close();
    }
}
```

```sql
DELIMITER; ;
CREATE DEFINER =`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `viewLeaderBoard`(pGameNumber INT(50))
BEGIN
    SELECT CharacterScore FROM tbl_character WHERE GameID = pGameNumber;
    SELECT CharacterName FROM tbl_character WHERE GameID = pGameNumber;
END; ;
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the two sql statements inside the stored procedure into a single query (in SQL you can select multiple fields in a SELECT statement):

```
SELECT CharacterScore, CharacterName FROM tbl_character WHERE GameID = pGameNumber;
```

Then you should be able to read it properly without code change.

To further improve the code, you can replace your try finally block with multiple [using statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) for `MySqlDataReader`, `MySqlConnection`. Also `MySqlCommand` implements `IDisposable` and should be disposed.

Comment: Are you able to show what you mean using the code?